# PHP query with OBDC connection returning string with unrecognized symbols

Tags: php, odbc

I am using ODBC connection to access a SQL Server database and get string from it. The problem is that I get `?` symbols in string where for example it should be `ē`.

This is the code I am using:

```
if(($result = odbc_exec($connect, $sql)) !== false) {
   while( $obj = odbc_fetch_object( $result )) {
      if ($obj->PLK_STATUSS == '10') {
            echo $obj->DESCRIPTION;
       }
    }
}
```

It should echo `Piemērs` but what I get is `Piem?rs`.

I have put

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"</meta>
```

in head. I also tried

```
echo utf8_decode($obj->DESCRIPTION);
```

with no luck.

What else could be a problem? I'm not experienced in php so probably it is something simple.

**EDIT:**
If I just do `echo "Piemērs";` then it works.

**EDIT:**
Im using FreeTDS to create ODBC connection. My guess is that problem is with ODBC configuration. From other sources I got that in freetds.conf file there should be line

```
client charset = UTF-8
```

But when I add this line web page stops working and I get `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is probably because of newer php version. Had the same problem where ODBC worked in php5 but when upgraded to php7 had to change it to PDO.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it changing from ODBC to PDO.

```
$conn = new PDO('dblib:charset=UTF-8;host='.Configure::read('SERVERNAME').';dbname='.Configure::read('DB'),
            Configure::read('USERNAME'),
            Configure::read('PASSWORD')
        );
```